# IE9 issue with drop down Box

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, coldfusion

I have a form that allows the user to search for a urgent care center near them. So the user can enter the name of a urgent care, city, how far from where they are at and zip code.

Works fine with chrome, firefox, and IE10/11 but not for IE9. I am not sure what is going on. I have been trying to see the issue and looking into it but no solution has been found

**UPDATE**
Let me clarify: What is not working is when you select the drop down box, their should be a list of cities. However it is blank. The same for the miles. By default, it should display a 5 mile range but it does not for IE9. I am not sure what the bug is.

The following is done in angular:

```
(
function(){
    var $scope, $location;
    var urgentCareApp = angular.module('urgentCareApp',['ui.bootstrap']);

    urgentCareApp.controller('UrgentCareController',function($scope,$http,$location,anchorSmoothScroll){
        $scope.Lang = 'initVal';
        $scope.ShowResults = false;
        $scope.ShowDesc = true;
        $scope.NoResults = false;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.maxPageNumbersToShow = 10;
        $scope.formModel = {};
        $scope.searchMode = 0;
        $scope.miles =  [{'value':'5'},{'value':'10'},{'value':'15'},{'value':'20' }];
        $scope.searchParam = {};

        $scope.searchParam.Distance = $scope.miles[0];
        console.log($scope.searchParam.Distance);
        //$scope.searchParam.Specialty = $scope.Specialties[0];

        $scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
            try{
                var lon, lat;
                console.log('starting geoposition code.');
                if("geolocation" in navigator){
                    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
                        lat = pos.coords.latitude.toFixed(3);
                        lon = pos.coords.longitude.toFixed(3);
                        console.log(lat + ' ' + lon);
                        $http.get("remote/ReturnCurrentZipcode.cfm?Lat=" + lat + "&Lon=" + lon)
                        .success(function(response){
                            console.log('Response: ' + response);
                            $scope.searchParam.Zip = response;
                            console.log('object set');
                        })
                    })
                }
                else if($scope.searchParam.Zip != ""){

                }
                else{ console.log('No geolocation'); }
            }
            catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }
        }

        $scope.GetCityList = function (){
            try{
                $http.get("remote/ReturnUrgentCareCityList.cfm")
                    .success(function(response){
                        $scope.Cities = response.Cities;
                    })
            }
            catch(err){}
        }

        $scope.SearchUrgentCare = function(searchParam){
            try{
                $scope.searchMode = 1;
                var queryString='';
                if($scope.formModel && $scope.formModel !== searchParam){
                    $scope.resultsCount = 0;
                    currentPage = 1;
                }
                if(searchParam){
                    $scope.formModel = searchParam;
                    for(var param in searchParam){
                        console.log(param + ' ' + searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param) + ' ' + searchParam[param]);
                        if(searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param)){
                            var paramValue = searchParam[param].value ? searchParam[param].value.trim() : searchParam[param].trim();
                            if (paramValue.length > 0)
                                queryString += param + '=' + paramValue + '&';
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(queryString);
                queryString= '?' + queryString + 'currentpage=' + $scope.currentPage;

                $http.get("remote/ReturnUrgentCareList.cfm" + queryString)
                .success(function(response){
                    $scope.urgentCareCenters = response.UrgentCareCenters;
                    $scope.resultsCount = response.rowCount;
                    if (!$scope.urgentCareCenters){
                            $scope.NoResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                    else{
                            $scope.NoResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                })
            }
            catch(err){ alert('No response.: ' + err.message); }
        }

        $scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage'], function(){
            try{
                if($scope.searchMode == 1){
                    $scope.SearchUrgentCare($scope.formModel);
                    }
            }
            catch(err){}
        });

        $scope.GetCityList();
        $scope.GetCurrentZip();

        $scope.gotoElement = function (eID){
            var browserWidth = screen.availWidth;
            if (browserWidth < 768)
                anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo(eID);
        };
    });

    urgentCareApp.service('anchorSmoothScroll', function(){
        this.scrollTo = function(eID) {

            // This scrolling function 
            // is from http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript

            var startY = currentYPosition();
            var stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
            var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
            if (distance < 100) {
                scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
            }
            var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
            if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
            var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
            var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
            var timer = 0;
            if (stopY > startY) {
                for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
                    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                    leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
                } return;
            }
            for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
                setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
            }

            function currentYPosition() {
                // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
                // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                    return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
                if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
                return 0;
            }

            function elmYPosition(eID) {
                var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
                var y = elm.offsetTop;
                var node = elm;
                while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                    node = node.offsetParent;
                    y += node.offsetTop;
                } return y;
            }
        };
    });

    urgentCareApp.directive('allowPattern',[allowPatternDirective]);
    function allowPatternDirective(){
        return{
            restrict: "A",
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
                return function(scope, element, attrs){
                    element.bind("keypress", function(event){
                        var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
                        var keyCodeChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

                        if(!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowPattern, "i"))){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    urgentCareApp.filter('PhoneNumber', function(){
    return function(phoneNumber){
        var dash = '-';
        if(phoneNumber){
            var pn = phoneNumber;
            pn = [pn.slice(0, 6), dash, pn.slice(6)].join('');
            pn = [pn.slice(0, 3), dash, pn.slice(3)].join('');
            return pn;
            }
        return phoneNumber;
        }
    });

})();

(function($) {
  // @todo Document this.
  $.extend($,{ placeholder: {
      browser_supported: function() {
        return this._supported !== undefined ?
          this._supported :
          ( this._supported = !!('placeholder' in $('<input type="text">')[0]) );
      },
      shim: function(opts) {
        var config = {
          color: '#888',
          cls: 'placeholder',
          selector: 'input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]'
        };
        $.extend(config,opts);
        return !this.browser_supported() && $(config.selector)._placeholder_shim(config);
      }
  }});

  $.extend($.fn,{
    _placeholder_shim: function(config) {
      function calcPositionCss(target)
      {
        var op = $(target).offsetParent().offset();
        var ot = $(target).offset();

        return {
          top: ot.top - op.top,
          left: ot.left - op.left,
          width: $(target).width()
        };
      }
      function adjustToResizing(label) {
        var $target = label.data('target');
        if(typeof $target !== "undefined") {
          label.css(calcPositionCss($target));
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(label); });
        }
      }
      return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if( $this.is(':visible') ) {

          if( $this.data('placeholder') ) {
            var $ol = $this.data('placeholder');
            $ol.css(calcPositionCss($this));
            return true;
          }

          var possible_line_height = {};
          if( !$this.is('textarea') && $this.css('height') != 'auto') {
            possible_line_height = { lineHeight: $this.css('height'), whiteSpace: 'nowrap' };
          }

          var isBorderBox = ($this.css('box-sizing') === 'border-box');
          var isTextarea = $this.is('textarea');

          var ol = $('<label />')
            .text($this.attr('placeholder'))
            .addClass(config.cls)
            .css($.extend({
              position:'absolute',
              display: 'inline',
              'float':'none',
              overflow:'hidden',
              textAlign: 'left',
              color: config.color,
              cursor: 'text',
              paddingTop: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-top'),
              paddingRight: $this.css('padding-right'),
              paddingBottom: !isTextarea && isBorderBox ? '0' : $this.css('padding-bottom'),
              paddingLeft: $this.css('padding-left'),
              fontSize: $this.css('font-size'),
              fontFamily: $this.css('font-family'),
              fontStyle: $this.css('font-style'),
              fontWeight: $this.css('font-weight'),
              textTransform: $this.css('text-transform'),
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              zIndex: 99,
            }, possible_line_height))
            .css(calcPositionCss(this))
            .attr('for', this.id)
            .data('target',$this)
            .click(function(){
                if (!$(this).data('target').is(':disabled')) {
                    $(this).data('target').focus();
                }
            })
            .insertBefore(this);
            $this
                .data('placeholder', ol)
                .on('keydown', function () {
                    ol.hide();
                })
                .on('blur change', function () {
                    ol[$this.val().length ? 'hide' : 'show']();
                })
                .triggerHandler('blur');
          $(window).one("resize", function () { adjustToResizing(ol); });
        }
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).add(window).bind('ready load', function() {
  if (jQuery.placeholder) {
    jQuery.placeholder.shim();
  }
});
```

The following is the form:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="hospital" ng-model="searchParam.HospitalName" placeholder="Hospital Name" type="text" /></div>

            <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City" ng-options="City.value for City in Cities"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> </select></div>

            <hr />
            <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 8pt !important; margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>

                            <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding">
                    <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll have to define what not working means and create a repro case before anyone can effectively help.

Comment: @MattBusche Hi, the issue is when the user select the city drop down box, it does expand but it is empty. The same with the zip code field. it should have by default display 5 miles

Comment: Obligatory: Microsoft doesn't even support IE9 anymore. I'm guessing you have clients or co-workers who simply can't upgrade to a browser from this side of the decade, but still. Do this under protest.

Comment: @TRose  Yes you are correct, clients and yet dont see reason. You dont see a way around this, in terms of coding. I am really new to coding and I have been just in a learning curve. Also, weird thing is, their is another page with the same exact code, a few different things here and their and yet it works. So I dont understand what is going on

Comment: Does any one else have objection on the matter?

Comment: @RobertoFlores I would recommend trying the browser's console and toying with the CSS or Javascript to see if anything you do makes it appear on IE9. The dev console can be accessed with F12.

Comment: AngularJS and legacy browsers do not fit together. You need to debug `ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"`. Although IE9 is still a somewhat supported browser, there might be edge cases that do not work properly.

Comment: @TRose I have went through the console and no errors appears. I have went through the html and css and the only thing I can see is the disabled feature that was on it and I set it to disabled. I figured it was a html tag and created a script to enable it but yet it didnt work

Comment: @Alex I have debugged them and yet no answers. I created another form, copy and paste what I did in this form and added a few fields and it worked. I dont understand why